# Translate a C# DLL external function declaration to Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, declaration

I have to translate this C# external function DLL declaration to Delphi:

```cs
[DllImport("CRT_571.dll")]
public static extern int ExecuteCommand(UInt32 ComHandle, byte TxAddr, byte TxCmCode, byte TxPmCode, UInt16 TxDataLen, byte[] TxData, ref byte RxReplyType, ref byte RxStCode0, ref byte RxStCode1, ref byte RxStCode2, ref UInt16 RxDataLen, byte[] RxData);
```

I've try with this:

```pascal
Type
  PTBytes = ^TBytes;

function ExecuteCommand(ComHandle: UInt32; TxAddr, TxCmCode, TxPmCode: byte; TxDataLen: UInt16; TxData: TBytes; var RxReplyType, RxStCode0, RxStCode1, RxStCode2: Byte; var RxDataLen: UInt16; RxData: PTBytes): integer; stdcall; external 'CRT_571.dll' name 'ExecuteCommand' delayed;
```

But, when I call the function, I get an 'Access Violation'.

Comment: Final arg should be PByte

Comment: Why tag c# if this is not actually concerning c#?

Answer (score 0):

Your translation is almost correct, but it does have a mistake - the `TxData` and `RxData` parameters should both be `PByte`, not `TBytes` and `PTBytes`, respectively.

```pascal
function ExecuteCommand(ComHandle: UInt32; TxAddr, TxCmCode, TxPmCode: Byte; TxDataLen: UInt16; TxData: PByte, var RxReplyType, RxStCode0, RxStCode1, RxStCode2: Byte; var RxDataLen: UInt16; RxData: PByte): Integer; stdcall; external 'CRT_571.dll';
```

`TBytes` is a Delphi-style dynamic `array of Byte`, which is not compatible with C#'s `byte[]` array type.  When C# marshals a `byte[]` array, if there is no `MarshalAs` to control the behavior of the marshaling (as is the case here), the marshaller's default behavior is to simply [pin the array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning) and pass a pointer to the array's 1st element.  Hence the use of `PByte` on the Delphi side.